# onclick check empty id val

Tags: javascript, jquery

можно ли реализовать подобный код?:

```
<input type text id="test"><a onclick ="if #test val empty return false">
```

тоесть чтоб не переходило по ссылке если input #test имеет пустое значение

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (document.getElementById('test').value.trim() === '') {
        e.preventDefault();
        // или 
        // return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Во многих браузерах элементы, у которых есть атрибут `id` доступны напрямую. Поэтому в inline обработчике к ним можно обратиться просто по `id`

Например:

```html
<input type text id="test"> <a onclick="return test.value.length>0" href="http://www.google.com">Link</a>
```